# Proof Expected utility vs Utility of expected value

Tags: probability, decision-theory

I have a feeling it is a trivial question, but I cannot see how to prove it.

Let $U(\mathbb{E}(p)) > U(\mathbb{E}(q))$,

where $p$ and $q$ are probability distribution

I need to show that
$\mathbb{E}[U_p] > \mathbb{E}[U_q]$, where the last expression can be written as $\int u(x)p(x)dx > \int u(x)q(x)dx$

How could I approach this problem?

Edit. Further assumptions

1. $F(x) < G(x)$ for every $x$, where $F()$ and $G()$ are the cdf of $p$ and $q$, respectively.
2. $U()$ increasing

Comment: I think some context is missing. how are $p$ and $q$ related.

Comment: The cdf of the first is assumed bigger than the second for every x (first order stochastic dominance, but there are no other assumptions. I think it is a matter of monotonicity of u() or something more basic

Comment: Write all your assumptions about $p$ and $q$ in the question explicitly.

Comment: Your cdf comment (in effect strict first-order stochastic dominance) is highly relevant, as otherwise there are counterexamples .  There also seems to be an implicit assumption that the utility function $U(x)$ is strictly increasing

Comment: @Henry could you pleasespecify which counterexaples could there be? That would help me understanding the problem

Comment: As a counter-example before your edit, suppose $P$ is a random variable taking the value $10$ with probability $0.8$ and $1000$ with probability $0.2$, while $Q$ is a random variable taking the value $100$ with probability $1$, and a logarithmic utility function $u(x)=\log_{10}(x)$.  Then $\mathbb{E}[P]=208 > 100 = \mathbb{E}[Q]$ and  $u(\mathbb{E}[P])\approx 2.318 > 2 = u(\mathbb{E}[Q])$ but $\mathbb{E}[u(P)] =1.4 < 2 =  \mathbb{E}[u(Q)]$

Comment: This question has been cross-posted [here](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/17491/expected-utility).

Comment: @luchonacho should I delete one of the two? because I did not get a reply on the other community at first

Comment: I would leave them, as they provide (imo) two different angles. As it turns out, the FSD assumption is essential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \hspace{-1.7cm} F(x) < G(x) $$

u(x) is increasing:

$
\begin{align*}
\implies-u'(x)F(x)&>-u'(x)G(x) &\text{}\\
\implies-\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}u'(x)F(x)&>-\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}u'(x)G(x) \\
\implies[u(x)F(x)]_{-\infty}^{+\infty}-\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}u'(x)F(x)&>[u(x)G(x)]_{-\infty}^{+\infty}-\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}u'(x)G(x)\\
\end{align*}$

From integration by parts:

$\begin{align*}
\hspace{3.1cm}\implies\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}u(x)dF(x)&>\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}u(x)dG(x)&\text{}\\
\implies\mathbb{E}(U_p)&>\mathbb{E}(U_q)
\end{align*}
$

I think there should be an additional assumption that p and q have common support and $u(x)$ is well defined in that support.

Comment: Could you please clearify where did you use the assumption that $U(E(p))>U(E(q))$?

Comment: You don't really need $U(E(p)) > U(E(q))$. It follows from the other two assumptions.
$$
\begin{align}
F(x)&<G(x)\\
\implies E(p) &> E(q)\;\;\text{from first order stochastic dominance}\\
\implies U(E(p)) &> U(E(q))\;\;\text{ U(x) is increasing}
\end{align}
$$